# How is DA equal to 1/x.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry

[Image of shape for question context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3DYL.png)

The question asked about this shape was...

"Let BP = x, and show that AB = AP = DP = 1, and DA = 1/x"

From what I extract, triangle ADB is isosceles where DA = DB, where DB = DP + BP, and from the question BP = x, and DP = 1 and therefore DA = 1 + x, not 1/x.

Is this question wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because the parts are in a golden ratio, $\frac{1}{x} = 1+x$ in this case. That is, provided the side length of the (regular) pentagon is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that our pentagon is equilateral.

We have  $$\Delta ADB\sim\Delta BAP,$$ which gives $$\frac{AD}{BA}=\frac{AB}{BP}$$ or   $$\frac{AD}{1}=\frac{1}{x},$$ which gives what you want.

By the way, we got also $$1+x=\frac{1}{x}.$$